# Динамическое создание виджетов pyqt

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qpushbutton

Решил я создать редактор заметок, для этого нужно создать функцию динамического создания элементов (нажимаю на кнопку, создается заметка, загружается в дб, при новом запуске проги выгружается с дб и появляется в проге).

Набросал код ниже, но там насколько я понял идёт переопределение pushButton_2
из за чего код работает не так:
(создаю "кнопка 1", нажимаю на неё, вывод "кнопка 1"| создаю "кнопка 2", нажимаю на неё, вывод "кнопка 2"| нажимаю "кнопка 1", "вывод кнопка 2" ).

Была идея обращаться к кнопке через setObjectName, но инфы в интернете так и не нашёл[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`

```
class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Form):

def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self._translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.click)

def click(self):
    text = input("текст кнопки: ")
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
    self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.click_2)
    self.pushButton_2.setText(self._translate("Form", text))

def click_2(self):
    print(self.pushButton_2.text())
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Придумал такой способ решение примера который описывал, попробую с этим играться.

```
    val = self.coppy_link_btn.text()
    self.coppy_link_btn.clicked.connect(lambda btn, text=val: self.onClicked(text))

    def onClicked(self,text):
            print(text)
```